# VariableReplacing is not working sometimes

Tags: java, docx4j

I am taking the docx file as a template, and when writing variables(${}) with Microsoft Word, not seeing some variables

But when I am changing it on LibreOffice, it is working(java seeing variable), but I can't do it everytime with LibreOffice!

```
File doc = new File("nameOfMyFile.docx");

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(doc);

MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

HashMap mappings = new HashMap();

VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage); 

mappings.put("lessonsEachWeek", contract.getHoursInWeek());

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().variableReplace(mappings);
Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File("someName.docx"));
```

XML of Docx file:

```
<w:r>
                            <w:rPr>
                                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                                <w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t xml:space="preserve">1.2 some text ${</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:rPr>
                                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                                <w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t>lessonsEachWeek</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:rPr>
                                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                                <w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t xml:space="preserve">} some text</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                    </w:p>
```

As you see brackets goes other runs, but when with LibreOffice:

```
<w:r>
                         <w:rPr>
                                <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Calibri"/>
                                <w:b/>
                                <w:bCs/>
                                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                                <w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t>${lessonsEachWeek}</w:t>
                        </w:r>
```

And the Error:

```
2019-07-17 15:00:57.097  WARN 10717 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.docx4j.XmlUtils                      : Invalid key '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/></w:rPr><w:t>lessonsEachWeek</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">' or key not mapped to a value
2019-07-17 15:00:57.097  WARN 10717 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.docx4j.XmlUtils                      : Invalid key '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/></w:rPr><w:t>lessonsEachWeek</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">' or key not mapped to a value
2019-07-17 15:00:57.135  INFO 10717 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.d.o.parts.WordprocessingML.BinaryPart  : .. closed.
```

Comment: What is the output of VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage)?

Comment: These XMLs are output of VariablePrepare

Comment: w:lang attributes differ, so prepare can't merge the runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause**

Word's text proofing feature have wrapped `lessonsEachWeek` text into some tags splitting it out from `${` and `}` tokens. Given such document docx4j tries to find substitution for key `</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr>...lessonsEachWeek...</w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">` while there is no such key, of course.

**Solution**

For existing document i was unable to find automated and graceful way to remove these wrapping tags, unfortunately. Disabling spell check in Word, rechecking and saving document doesn't work for some reason. I have done some "manual surgery": opened docx file in 7z as zip file, located \word\document.xml in it, F4 (edit) and removed these wrapping tags. 7z repacked zip file, Word still opens it without a problem while my Java / Kotlin application can now substitute keys that were fixed! Any similar archiver and editor should also do the trick.

**How to avoid this problem in new documents**

Disable text proofing in Word when creating such templates.

"File" -> "Options" -> "Proofing", uncheck all checkboxes in "When correcting spelling and grammar in Word" section.